# I am Having a Trouble in my DFS Search (Tree) Code. How can I break Recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

The way i used to search the Tree is through a recursion.
 I was wondering if I could break from the recursion and reach the program to it's normal flow.
So basically I'm trying to say is, Is there a way to break from a recursion without back tracking the stack?
If not can anyone suggest me some other way?

**BinaryTree Class**

```
class BinaryTree
{
public:
    template <class T>
    class Node {
    public:
        Node(T item) {
            this->item = item;
            this->left = nullptr;
            this->right = nullptr;
        }
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        T item;
    };
    BinaryTree();
    template<class T>
    void DFS(Node<T> *N);
private:
    Node<char>* root;

};


BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
    this->root = new Node<char>('A');
    this->root->left = new  Node<char>('B');
    this->root->right = new  Node<char>('C');
    this->root->left->left = new  Node<char>('D');
    this->root->left->right = new  Node<char>('E');
    this->root->right->left = new  Node<char>('F');
    this->root->right->right = new  Node<char>('G');
    this->DFS(root);
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree::DFS(Node<T>* N) {
    if(N == nullptr)
        return;
    cout << N->item << endl;
    if( N->item == 'E') {
       cout << "found\n";
       //Break from recursion;
    }

    DFS(N->left);
    DFS(N->right);
}
```

**Output Generated**

```
A
B
D
E
found
C
F
G
```

**Output Required**

```
A
B
D
E
found
```

Comment: What is the "Trouble"? Do you have a concrete problem, or are you just asking for a way to rewrite the code to produce the same result but work differently?

Comment: I want the program to break the recursion after the item is found.

Comment: return; is what you want to write in the commented line

Comment: Return won't end the recursion. I want to break out of it . Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that came to my mind:

```
template <class T>
bool BinaryTree::DFS(Node<T>* N) {
    if(N == nullptr)
        return false;
    cout << N->item << endl;
    if( N->item == 'E') {
       cout << "found\n";
       return true;
    }

    if(DFS(N->left))
        return true;
    if(DFS(N->right))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You would, however, need to change the return type in the class declaration.